# How to redirect to controller with parameter value in route

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have `asp.net core MVC 2.2` application with below routing configured in `startup.cs`

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Then in `Author` Controller i have action method that redirects user to another route by passing parameter

```
[Area("Tasks")]
public class AuthorController: Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Preview(AuthorModel model)
   {
      return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Preview", new { area = "Tasks", id=model.id});
   }
}
```

This creates the route `/Tasks/Preview?id=1`

Then in `Preview` controller i have

```
[Area("Tasks")]
public class PreviewController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]        
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int templateID)
    {
        // do something here to get model
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This is working fine.

However i want the `id` to be passed as route value not as querystring. So route should look like `/Tasks/Preview/1`

What do i need to change?

Comment: Have you tried to change the parameter `templateID` to `id`?

Comment: ahh didn't realize i was using `templateID`. Yes changing the id works but it creates the route as `/Tasks/Preview/Index/1` what i want is `/Tasks/Preview/1`.  I added explicit `route` attribute on the top of preview->index method `[Route("Tasks/Preview/{id?}")]` to get it working